# broadleaf commerce 404 on index page

Tags: java, spring-boot, broadleaf-commerce

The broadleaf works well in my local development environment, but when I deployed to the server, the **index page** return 404 error but the other page working well
[image]

[image]

When I visit those pages, they both log, so I guess there are visited but somehow index page can't be found?

```
2020-11-01 23:18:10.809  WARN 13064 --- [io-8443-exec-10] .c.w.p.GoogleUniversalAnalyticsProcessor : No trackers were found, not outputting Google Analytics script. Set the googleAnalytics.webPropertyId and/or the googleAnalytics.masterWebPropertyId system properties to output Google Analytics
```

Comment: you have a few chrome plugins installed. Is any of them an tracking/ad blocker? Perhaps try a browser that isn't chrome as a quick test?

Comment: @RobEvans , open in firefox, safari but still page not found on the index page

Answer (score 0):

That warning is not likely preventing the page from loading. To use the Google Analytics processor, set the property `googleAnalytics.webPropertyId` to your web property id from Google Analytics.

If you do not want to use the processor, remove the `<blc:google_universal_analytics>` tag from your HTML templates, likely in `head.html`.